# How to use a default Google Assistant agent on an Android Things device?

Tags: actions-on-google, android-things, google-assistant-sdk

I’m playing with the [Google Assistant Sample code for Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant). I’ve got the example working, but is there a way to always start the conversation with a particular agent?

Without having to say “Talk to my Test Robot Thing” or similar first?

I’m working on a project for entertainment purposes (an animated robot that has some canned physical actions and answers questions), but it takes the fun out of it if you have to talk to the default Google Assistant first (and any time your agent stops).  In other words, can I have the Google Assistant in my Android Things device permanently bound to my agent?

Comment: I could also try to use something something similar to [Custom Device Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview), but AFAIK I can only handle simple actions this way, not define conversation responses (a la DiagFlow) to give my toy robot a personality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Device Actions as a way to trigger an action when the user says a specific phrase. This is for single-event commands, which are not conversational.

Anything beyond that would need to be handled as a custom implementation, perhaps making calls to Dialogflow and handling the response in a more conversational way.

Comment: Thanks @NickFelker!  Do you have any pointers on how to implement a custom implementation as you suggest?

Comment: [This page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions) of the docs is a good start in showing how to create and test an action package.

Comment: I was hoping for an example of how to make calls into DiagFlow to handle the response in a "more conventional" way.

Comment: Dialogflow and custom actions are divergent. They don't hook into one another.